# How to build phrase language translation engine in Java

Tags: java, internationalization

In the process of designing an engine which will be used to translate phrases that are processed by the application.

The ideal is to look for a set element in the XML, identify it by its category and then submit it to a translation engine that will check to see if the phrase has already been converted or needs to be.  If it does it will be placed into a translation table.

The basic structure of the table A is:

```
element_id | element_type | category_type | value | language_id
```

Now there is a GUI that will be used to do the translation.  User will select a given element and category from drop downs along with the from language and the to language.

Using the element, category and language a list will be display of those items that have not been converted.

User then will enter in the converted phrase.

The thought to manage all this is to use a mapping table:

```
mapping_id | element_from_id | element_to_id | from_language | to_language
```

So lets say we have the following in the first table

```
1 | DMG_AREA | DAMAGE | Quarter Panel - Left | EN
```

User translates it into FR using the GUI

Now table looks like this:

```
1 | DMG_AREA | DAMAGE | Quarter Panel - Left | EN
2 | DMG_AREA | DAMAGE | QPL                  | FR
```

The second table looks like this

```
1 | 1 | 2 | EN | FR
2 | 2 | 1 | FR | EN
```

So that we can then build the resource bundles by doing a simple query of Table B to determine the key/value pair for a "resource bundle" hashmap that will be placed into memory for on the fly translation.

Suggestions for improvement - does it make sense - is there a simpler way - open source solution already out there?

Comment: 1 / 1 / 5 / EN / FR - where did the 5 come from and should it be a 2?

Comment: Correction has been made - thanks

Comment: Can you say something about the scope of the phrases? Is it very domain specific or completely general?

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time, you'd be better off leveraging on the power of the [Google Translate API](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Translate_API) than maintaining your own local translation table.